# using django regroup tag equivalent in python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a project built with django whereby I use django's template engine. I want to switch the frontend from django template engine to reactjs. Everything works quite well using django template engine. I have googled and stackoverflowed everywhere but no solution to my problem.
Here is what I did using django template engine (everything works well):

```
# models.py

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    publish = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now,
        verbose_name=("Publication date"),
    )
    ...
```

My templatetag looks like this:

```
# blog_tags.py

@register.inclusion_tag('blog/month_links_snippet.html')
def render_month_links():
    all_posts = Post.published.dates('publish', 'month', order='DESC')
    return {'all_posts': all_posts,}
```

My template file looks like this:

```
# blog/month_links_snippet.html

{% regroup all_posts by year as dates_by_year %}
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="active list-unstyled">
    {% for month in dates_by_year %}
        <li id="year{{ month.grouper }}"{% if forloop.first %} class="active"{% endif %}>
        <h2 style="font-size: 18px"><a href="{% url 'blog:archive-year' month.grouper %}">{{ month.grouper }}</a> <i class="collapsing-icon fa fa-plus"></i></h2>
        <div class="collapsing-content">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
            {% for d in month.list %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'blog:archive_month_numeric' d|date:"Y" d|date:"n" %}">{{ d|date:"F Y" }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Everything works as expected. Take a look:

[Blog post archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Weoui.png)

**How can I achieve this using django rest framework?**

Please remember that this data will later be consumed by reactjs.

These are the methods that I have tried so far with DRF

**Method 1**

```
# models.py

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    publish = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now,
        verbose_name=("Publication date"),
    )
    ...
    
    def date(self):
        return self.publish.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

My serializers module looks like this:

```
# serializers.py

class PostArchiveSidebarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    publish = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y")
    date= serializers.SerializerMethodField(source="date")
    class Meta: 
        model = Post
        fields = ["publish", "date"]

    def get_date(self, obj):
        return obj.date()
```

My views module looks like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
@api_view(["GET"])
def year_month_archive(request):
    # published = PublishedManager() my custom manager.
    posts = Post.published.filter(status='published').order_by('-publish')
    serializer = PostArchiveSidebarSerializer(posts, many=True)
    grouped = groupby(serializer.data, itemgetter('date'))
    new_data = {k:next(v) for k, v in grouped}
    # I use the next() func to make the month unique for a specific year
    return Response(new_data)
```

**Method 1 output**

```
{
    "2021-08-31": {
        "publish": "2021",
        "date": "2021-08-31"
    },
    "2020-12-05": {
        "publish": "2020",
        "date": "2020-12-05"
    },
    "2020-05-17": {
        "publish": "2020",
        "date": "2020-05-17"
    },
    "2020-04-06": {
        "publish": "2020",
        "date": "2020-04-06"
    },
    "2020-03-12": {
        "publish": "2020",
        "date": "2020-03-12"
    },
    "2020-02-09": {
        "publish": "2020",
        "date": "2020-02-09"
    },
    "2019-09-13": {
        "publish": "2019",
        "date": "2019-09-13"
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
# models.py

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    publish = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now,
        verbose_name=("Publication date"),
    )
    ...
```

No serializers needed here

```
# views.py

from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from django.template.defaultfilters import date

@api_view(["GET"])
def year_month_archive(request):
    year_frequency = defaultdict(int)
    all_posts = Post.published.dates("publish", "month", order="DESC")
    for year in all_posts:
        format_month = date(year, 'F Y')
        year_frequency[year.year] += 1
        year_frequency[format_month] += 1
    count_year = list(Counter(year_frequency))

    return Response({'archive': count_year})
```

**Method 2 output**

```
{
    "archive": [
        2021,
        "August 2021",
        2020,
        "December 2020",
        "May 2020",
        "April 2020",
        "March 2020",
        "February 2020",
        2019,
        "September 2019"
    ]
}
```

My goal is to create an accordion with year `2021` as the title and `August 2021` as the content.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

This is my first question in here